# What is the name of the font when labeling an inference rule?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, macros, packages

What is the font of *Foo* in this inference rule?

[image]

The package being used for the inference rule is https://ctan.org/pkg/mathpartir?lang=en.
The example is found on page 7.

Another question if somebody manages to find out the name of the font:
How would I go about defining a macro that takes as input some text and outputs the text with that font and size?

Comment: You seem to be referring not to a font, but a font "shape" called "small caps".  One obtains it typically with `\textsc{Total}` or `\textsc{Foo}`.

Comment: Font is default font. Inputting `...[Left=Foo...]` eventually leads, via `\LeftTirNameStyle`, to small small-caps: `\small \textsc{Foo}`. Also, the label styles can be redefined: "Instead of just changing the style, the whole typesetting of labels may be changed by redefining `\DefTirName`, `\LabTirName`, `\LeftTirName`, and `\RightTirName`, each of which receives the label to be typeset as argument." (p 8). E.g., normal-size small-caps for Left is: `\def \LeftTirName #1{\textsc{#1}}`.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the clarification.